# Prometheum Exxet: What happens when you want to apply a level 1 power to ammunition?

Tags: magic-items, crafting, anima-beyond-fantasy

When creating magical ammunition using the Prometheum Exxet, the cost of powers is supposed to be reduced by one level.  What happens if that level is 1?

Specifically, in a sidebar on page 21, the Prometheum Exxet states:

> The creation of supernatural ammunition is simple compared to the processes required for more sophisticated weapons. Therefore, the Power Points costs of powers added to various types of ammunition are treated as one Power Level lower on the appropriate table.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be lower than level 1 I should think. Based on the wording it is intended for higher level powers being applied. Perhaps it could be ruled that points produced at level 1 are worth double for the purposes of level 1 powers for ammunition. Seems a bit gamey though.

Comment: Well, yes, it is in fact, a game, but yeah.